# Cross-Domain AJAX issue trying to load JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain

I have a URL(that i am not in control of) that returns a JSON string. This JSON string contains a URL that i am trying to load with JavaScript/jQuery AJAX. What I’m running in to when loading the JSON string is a Cross-Domain issue.

I know a couple of workarounds for fixing Cross-Domain issues like:

- Using JSONP by adding "callback=?” as a parameter.
- Call for example a PHP script and letting it load and return the JSON.

My issue is that i JSONP is not supported and i can’t do the convinient method of using PHP on the server because of the problem below:

The URL in the JSON data has one dynamically generated parameter. As from what i understand when playing around with it the dynamically generated parameter is that it is defined by whats loading the JSON, specifically the User-Agent string. But it is also depending on the IP loading the JSON. This is important because the URL inside the JSON string will return 403 forbidden if whats loading the JSON is not matching whats loading the URL.

I hope i have explained my issue well and i appreciate all help i can get.

Comment: This is probably a security measure designed to stop you doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why would you expect anyone here to be motivated to help you hack past some site's API security?

Answer (score 0):

As [Quentin said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27770968/cross-domain-ajax-issue-trying-to-load-json#comment43952954_27770968), it sounds like a security measure designed to stop you doing what you are trying to do. So you can't do it. That, or you implement a query from a server and reverse-engineer how to deal with the dynamically-generated parameter, but note that you'll almost certainly be violating some terms of service that the service in question seems to take seriously. And so after a few days of working, don't be surprised if it stops working when they figure out what you're doing and patch it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will not try to do some reverse engernering to get past this. I was looking for a clue to if i was missing some tecnique of solving Cross-Domain issues like this, but it might be so that this is the the API security and then i will not try to fiddle with it.